# Is there a way to change the printed string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, colors

Is there a way to change the color of a printed text in python example `print("Hello world")` and change its color to like blue when it gets printed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print colored text to the terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/how-to-print-colored-text-to-the-terminal)

Comment: What have you [researched](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3929826) so far?

Answer (score 1):

```
pip install termcolor
#https://pypi.org/project/termcolor/

from termcolor import colored 

print(colored("Jello World!", 'green'))
```